# View with .fetch() not rendering

Tags: backbone.js, view, render

When I render this view

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
/* el : '.myview', used when rendered on router request */
    render : function () {
        var data = new Data(); /* a collection from ajax request */
        var that = this;

        data.fetch({
            success : function (bla, data) {
                var template = _.template( $('#temp').html(), {data: data.players} );
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

on router request, it works:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        'bla' : 'bla'
    }
});

var myView = new MyView();

var router = new Router();
router.on('route:bla', function () {
    myView.render();
});
```

But when I want it simply to load with the page, it doesn't:

```
var myView = new MyView({ el: $(".myview") });
```

Comment: Does it give you any error ? And can you try specifying `el` as just `".myview"` instead of `$(".myview")` in the line `var myView = new MyView({ el: $(".myview") });` ?

Comment: @Cyclone No errors, and removing $() makes no difference

Comment: Is the view initialization being done after the DOM is ready ?

Comment: @Cyclone Yes, why? it is wrapped in `$(function(){`

Comment: The reason why I asked so is, when the piece of code which initializes and renders the view, is executed, `view` will try to create a `jquery cached` object of the `el` specified, if the specified element is not there in the DOM, then it won't be able to render anything.

Comment: And when are you calling `render` after creating the view ?

Comment: @Cyclone Yes, you can look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6T0RtKxIyBs3oOJ0PlC8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the last line you posted, you missing call to render function.

```
var myView = new MyView({ el: $(".myview") });
myView.render();
```

Besides of that, I see the workflow of initialization a bit wiered. Namely, requesting the data inside `.render()` function, that violates view single responsibility. Something, that I do in my applications.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        'bla' : 'bla'
    },

    bla: function () {
        app.BlaApp();
    }
});

app.BlaApp = function () {
    var collection = new Collection();
    collection.fetch({
        success: function (collection) {
            var view = new app.BlaView({model: collection});
            view.render();
        }
    })
}

app.BlaView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var template = // render template based on this.model;
        this.$el.html(template);

        return this;
    }
});
```